# How do we build a jar for a project downloaded from the internet

Tags: java, eclipse

I have had this doubt for a long time . I download a project from the internet . It has the entire set .(The source and the other resources) . I want to build a jar file using eclipse . This might sound simple but since its downloaded from the internet this structure looks confusing and i am unaware as to how a jar file has to be built out of that

Comment: What is you exact problem? Usually it is as simple as this : Import the project in eclipse, then right click on it and then export it as jar

Comment: I don have the project file as such . its just a folder which i downloaded from the internet . My problem is getting it into eclipse

Comment: You need to import it first. In eclipse File > Import.. > General > Existing projects into workspace

Comment: why don't you share the link to project for better answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
in eclipse select project 
    1:right click on project 
    2: select export
    3:java then jar
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all import the project in Eclipse, resolve all its dependencies required by the project, so that there are no compilation errors. Then right click on the project in Eclipse and then select:

```
Export > Java > Jar
```

Follow the instructions and this should export out the project as a JAR file.

Comment: I don have it as an already existing project . Its a folder i downloaded from the internet

Comment: If it is a Java project, then create a new Java project and copy the class files with the package structure from the downloaded inside the src directory. As I said you need to manually resolve all the dependencies so that there aren't any compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

If you downloaded the folder, you need to figure out it's root folder that should be src right below trunk. You can figure out the structure from looking at package declaration in java files. Try setting up the package properly in eclipse and it will start working.

But the best way is to look at the source again from where you downloaded and check out the project as svn or something similar. I am sure if it is a fully functional project, it should be available for checkout from repository.

Lastly you probably should rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

In modern practices, projects often contain build configuration for packaging to jars, deploy to web servers, such as ant, maven for java.
If not, i just simply wait for refactoring on build process or do it by myself.
Just a thought but not helpful :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried exporting it as jar from eclipse? To do this: Select your project, right click on it and select `Export`. Select `JAR file`, select `next`. Select your project and maintain the export destination and a name for the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

[create jar file in eclipse](http://www.eclipse-blog.org/eclipse-jar/exportingimporting-jar-files.html)

```
right click --->export --->jar file-->next
```